# set alpha level of listview selected rows android

Tags: android

I have a listview which contains list of `imageview`.In listView I am using `onLongItemClickListener()`.So my scenario is when i do a long click on my listview items it should change its alpha value(opaque) on the selected row .I have tried :

```
 @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    image.setAlpha(0.8f);
    return true;
}
```

but it didn't worked out.Can anyone solve my problem.

Comment: the `View` that's being clicked is `view` so you should do something like this: `view.setAlpha(0.8f);`

Comment: ok setAlpha method is now working i just placed it in a wrong place:)